# How to print numbers in a triangle pattern?

Tags: java, numbers

Below is the pattern I would like to print in the console:

```
                1
          2     0     2
    3     0     0     0     3
```

And below is the code I have right now. Each number should have 5 spaces between each other.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Input the number of lines you want to print.");
         Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n = a.nextInt();
         int[] row = new int[0];
         for(int i=0 ; i < n ; i++){
             row = nextRow(row);
              for(int j=0;j < n-i;j++){
                 
                //Padding For Triangle
                System.out.print(" ");
                 
            }
            //Output the values
          for(int j=0 ; j < row.length ; j++){
                 
                System.out.print(row[j]+" ");
         
            }
            //Start New Line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    /*Find Values Of Next Row*/
    public static int[] nextRow(int row[]){
         
        int nextRow[] = new int [row.length+1];
         
        nextRow[0] = row.length+1;               
        nextRow[nextRow.length-1] =row.length+1;
        for(int i=1 ; i < nextRow.length-1 ; i++){
             
            nextRow[i] = 0;
        }
        return nextRow;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: This is not clear enough. Please reformulate

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: The question is to print the pattern as i given. What i print right now is:1                                                                        2         2

Comment: sorry i don't know exactly how to print the pattern here...

Comment: it is three lines with first line 1 and second line 2 and 2 and third line 3,0,3. Not what the question asks...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some modified code. Its not complete and still something need to update your code to get desired result. That part I am leaving it for you. I also left hint in code so that you could modify.

`1.`

```
     // Padding For Triangle
     System.out.print("      "); // 6 white space
```

`2.`

```
     System.out.print(row[k]);
     System.out.print("     "); // 5 white space
```

`3.`

```
    /* Find Values Of Next Row */
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static int[] nextRow(int row[]) {
        int nextRow[] = null;
        if (row.length == 0) {
            nextRow = new int[1];
            nextRow[0] = 1;
        } else {
            // count++; // Hint
            nextRow = new int[row.length + 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < nextRow.length; i++) {
                if ((i == 0 || i == nextRow.length - 1)) {

                    nextRow[i] = nextRow.length - 2;
                    // nextRow[i] = count;

                } else {
                    nextRow[i] = 0;

                }
            }
        }
        return nextRow;
    }
```

If you have any questions, just ask. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to identify the pattern that the output expects, which in your case is:

```
Row0, columns 1
Row1, columns 3
Row2, columns 5
Row3, columns 7
```

which is, rowNum*2+1

Based, on this, I modified your code and here is the working solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Input the number of lines you want to print.");
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = a.nextInt();
    int[] row = null;
    for(int i=0 ; i < n ; i++){
        row = nextRow(i);
        for(int j=0;j < n-i;j++){
            //Padding For Triangle
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        //Output the values
        for(int j=0 ; j < row.length ; j++){
            System.out.print(row[j]+" ");
        }
        //Start New Line
        System.out.println();
    }
}
/*Find Values Of Next Row*/
public static int[] nextRow(int rowNum){
    int nextRow[] = new int [rowNum*2+1];

    nextRow[0] = rowNum+1;//-rowNum/2;
    nextRow[nextRow.length-1] = nextRow[0];
    for(int i=1 ; i < nextRow.length-1 ; i++){
        nextRow[i] = 0;
    }
    return nextRow;
}
}
```

And here is some output:

2:

```
    1
  2 0 2
```

5:

```
          1 
        2 0 2 
      3 0 0 0 3 
    4 0 0 0 0 0 4 
  5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
```

10:

```
                   1 
                 2 0 2 
               3 0 0 0 3 
             4 0 0 0 0 0 4 
           5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 
         6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 
       7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 
     8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 
   9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10
```

Answer (score -1):

i saw your code, i think that we can do this, follow is my modified code:

```
public class Triangle {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Input the number of lines you want to print.");
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = a.nextInt();
    int [] row = new int[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        row = nextRow(row);
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {

            // Padding For Triangle
            System.out.print("   ");

        }
        // Output the values
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {

            System.out.print(row[j] + "     ");

        }
        // Start New Line
        System.out.println();
    }
}

/* set space between each other. */
public static String printSpace(int n) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += "     ";// 5 space
    }

    return result;
}

/* Find Values Of Next Row */
public static int [] nextRow(int row[]) {

    int nextRow[] = new int[row.length + 1];

    nextRow[0] = row.length + 1;
    nextRow[nextRow.length - 1] = row.length + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < nextRow.length - 1; i++) {

        nextRow[i] = 0;
    }
    return nextRow;
}
```

}

---

may be this is answer what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Look up the arithmetic sequence for printing out the zeros, the rest should be trivial.

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down vote people so that we can improve in the future....there is no point in only down voting and then running away, it makes no change.